# Opentsdb Port Security

Tags: hadoop, hbase, time-series, grafana, opentsdb

I am successfully running the opentsdb with port 4242 and gathering the metrics from system. But, the issue we are facing practically is that anyone can gather the metrics from TSDB server by using the port 4242 and draw the graphs.

What are good tips for securing the port 4242? Metrics should be gathered only by authenticating the port by a system like Graphana and not by simply typing the url : 192.168.1.1:4242

Comment: You can always restrict access to required ports with iptables.

Comment: Hi Sergei Rodionov,Thanks for your comments. I know that we can secure with iptables and let me know if any alternative methods or tool ?